# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE query is skipping last character of first and last words from the input file

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find the reason.

MySQL query:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'ABC' INTO TABLE some_db.some_table;`

Contents of ABC:

```
"AXXXXXXXXXXXXB6"   "AAAAAA"    "Yellow1"   "0000009030"
"AXXXXXXXXXXXXC7"   "BBBBBB"    "Greeen1"   "0000008030"
```

Data which finally gets inserted:

```
+-----------------+----------+-----------+------------+
| ITY_SER_NO      | SGH_NO   | SGH_DESC  | RANDOMG_ID |
+-----------------+----------+-----------+------------+
| "AXXXXXXXXXXXXB | "RA7F00" | "Yellow1" | "000000903 |
| "AXXXXXXXXXXXXC | "RA7F00" | "Greeen1" | "000000803 |
|                 |          |           |            |
|                 |          |           |            |
+-----------------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

It skips last character, "6" from the first string "AXXXXXXXXXXXXB6" and also skips the quote and then it skips the last character, "0" from the last string, "0000009030". So, in each line it skips the last character (and quote) from the first and last strings.

Can I change my query to do this?

Comment: What are the column lengths ? Please share the table structure.

Comment: Oops your question made me realise. Stupid mistake! The column length was not enough. Thanks @AbhikChakraborty